# trigger to populate xy columns in sql spatial table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

THe method to retrieve X and Y coordinates in WKT from a SQL spatial column seems rather easy:

SELECT 
Shape.STX AS [X Coordinate],
Shape.STY AS [Y Coordinate]
FROM table

But I have an operational requirement to report the X and Y values in columns in the same table for consumption by the end user. Given that this is legacy data, some of the XY columns are already populated, many are not. So, how would one define a trigger to populate col.x and col.y on update or insert, and populate the existing null col.x and col.y?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just perform one pass of the data now, assuming that your inserts and updates going forward will populate this data correctly?

```
UPDATE table 
 SET X_Coord = SHAPE.STX, Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY
 WHERE X_Coord IS NULL;
```